# && operator in a javascript function return statement not supposed to return a boolean

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
function getLabelContent(element) {
    var label = element.find('label');
    return label[0] && label.html();
 }
```

I am puzzled about the **return statement** and especially the `&&` operator which I thought was used to evaluate operands of a boolean expression.

What does the above return statement mean please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators do not return boolean values in JavaScript.

```
a = b && c;
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
a = !b ? b : c;
```

while

```
a = b || c;
```

is essentially equivalent to:

```
a = b ? b : c;
```

---

The coalescing behavior of these operators is useful in some circumstances.

For the `||` operator it can be used to help extend namespaces that may or may not exist:

```
//use window.foo if it exists, otherwise create it
window.foo = window.foo || {};
```

The `&&` operator is often used for safe console logging:

```
//don't call console.log if there's no console
window.console && console.log('something');
```

Comment: This is awesome to know

Comment: +1 for showing usage cases.

Comment: By the way `b && c;` is not exactly equivalent to `!b ? b : c;` when `b` is falsy but not false

Comment: @megawac - I don't think that's correct: `"" && true` returns `""`

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles whoops you're correct misconception thanks

Comment: np, just wanted to clarify for the guy asking the question :)