# In JavaScript, why does (undefined && true) return undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using the node.js console (node 0.10.24)

```
> var x = (undefined && true);
undefined
> x;
undefined
> x = (true && undefined);
undefined
> x;
undefined
```

Why does the comparison return undefined? I would expect it to return false since undefined is considered "falsey".

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22105549/497418

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `&&` operator proceeds by *internally* coercing the values of the expressions to boolean, but the *result* of the operator is always the actual, uncoerced value of the first expression that failed (i.e., that was falsey).

Thus `(true && undefined)` will result in `undefined` because `true` is *not* falsey.  Similarly, `(true && 0)` would evaluate to `0`.

Comment: The result is the uncoerced value of the _first_ expression that failed (because execution stops as soon as one fails).

Comment: @AaronDufour oh right; durr. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In javascript `||` and `&&` are not guaranteed to return boolean values, and will only do so when the operands are booleans.

`a = b || c` is essentially a shortcut for:

```
a = b ? b : c;
```

`a = b && c` is essentially a shortcut for:

```
a = b ? c : b;
//or
a = !b ? b : c;
```

Comment: You can "see" them similar in the some cases, but it doesn't mean it works under the hood that way. console.log('a'=='b' && 'c') is different from console.log('a'=='b'?'c':'b')

Answer (score 5):

To formalize what others are saying, here's what the [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11) says about how the logical AND operator is evaluated:

> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating LogicalANDExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. If ToBoolean(lval) is false, return lval.
> 4. Let rref be the result of evaluating BitwiseORExpression.
> 5. Return GetValue(rref).

And perhaps most relevant, the note at the bottom of section 11.11:

> The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type
>   Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two
>   operand expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I was wasting my time looking at the docs for "undefined", and not the AND operator

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are more than adequate, I'm including my answer here for posterity just in case someone else's brain works like mine:

The result of the boolean `||` and boolean `&&` operators will always be the result of the last expression evaluated, taking into consideration short circuiting.

So, for `||`, if the first expression is [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), short circuit evaluation means that the rest is ignored, and the result will be the value of that first expression.  If it's [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), evaluation must continue to the second expression, and the result will be the result of that second expression no matter whether it's truthy or falsy.

Likewise for `&&`, if the first expression is [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) then evaluation stops and the result is the result of that first expression, if it's [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) then evaluation continues and the result is the result of the second expression.